# TypeError: Must be str, not int error occuring

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to send the data from a CGI script to a C server in order to write the data down to an XML file.

Client.cgi:

```
import cgi, cgitb
import os
import sys
import argparse
import requests
from requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning
requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings()
import sys
import socket


form = cgi.FieldStorage()


#--PARSING THE ARGUMENTS
#--To be used to get arguments from Command Line or Php Script
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description ='parser script')
parser.add_argument('--serverId', required=True, help='Server ID to find device info')
parser.add_argument('--name', required=True, help='Name Of the Policy')
parser.add_argument('--host', default='any', help='Host of the IP Address')
parser.add_argument('--port', default='any', help='Port used')
parser.add_argument('--proto', default='any', help='Protocol used')
parser.add_argument('--username', default='any', help='Username')
parser.add_argument('--password', default='any', help='Password')
parser.add_argument('--key', default='any', help='')
parser.add_argument('--companyName', default='any', help='Name of the Company')
parser.add_argument('--officeAddress', default='any', help='Address of the Company')
parser.add_argument('--state', default='any', help='State')
parser.add_argument('--country', default='any', help='Country')
parser.add_argument('--ladmin', default='any', help='Local Admin')
parser.add_argument('--phone', default='any', help='Phone Number')
parser.add_argument('--mobile', default='any', help='Mobile Number')
parser.add_argument('--email', default='any', help='Email Address')
parser.add_argument('--designation', default='any', help='Designation of the concerned')
parser.add_argument('--rManager', default='any', help='Reporting Manager of the concerned Person')

args = parser.parse_args()


#--Associating variables to parsed arguments
serverId = str(args.serverId)
name = str(args.name)
host = str(args.host)
port = str(args.port)
proto = str(args.proto)
user = str(args.username)
password = str(args.password)
key = str(args.key)
company = str(args.companyName)
officeAddr = str(args.officeAddress)
state = str(args.state)
country = str(args.country)
ladmin = str(args.ladmin)
phone = str(args.phone)
mobile = str(args.mobile)
email = str(args.email)
designation = str(args.designation)
reportingMgr = str(args.rManager)

def client_program():
    host = socket.gethostname()  # as both code is running on same pc
    port = 8888  # socket server port number

    client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)  # instantiate
    client_socket.connect((host, port))  # connect to the server

    sum = serverId+";"+name+";"+host+";"+port+";"+proto+";"+user+";"+password+";"+key+";"+company+";"+officeAddr+";"+state+";"+country+";"+ladmin+";"+phone+";"+mobile+";"+email+";"+designation+";"+reportingMgr

    client_socket.sendall(sum.encode('utf-8'))
    data = client_socket.recv(1024)
    text = str(data)

    print('received:' +text)
    print('closing socket')
    client_socket.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    client_program()
```

when passing arguments through command line like

```
python dscr.cgi --serverId PA124 --name Devanshu
```

I get a traceback call as folowing

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dscr.cgi", line 90, in <module>
    client_program()
  File "dscr.cgi", line 79, in client_program
    sum = serverId+";"+name+";"+host+";"+port+";"+proto+";"+user+";"+password+";"+key+";"+company+";"+officeAddr+";"+state+";"+country+";"+ladmin+";"+phone+";"+mobile+";"+email+";"+designation+";"+reportingMgr
TypeError: must be str, not int
```

I realise that its nothing but a silly mistake but I'm unable to find out what. Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `port` variable is an int, you must convert it to `str` first:

You are in fact converting `port` to a `str` at some moment, but later assign it to an int in the scope of the function: `port = 8888`.
Maybe the remnant of some debugging code?

```
#                                       **here**
    sum = serverId+";"+name+";"+host+";"+str(port)+";"+proto+";"+user+";"+password+";"+key+";"+company+";"+officeAddr+";"+state+";"+country+";"+ladmin+";"+phone+";"+mobile+";"+email+";"+designation+";"+reportingMgr
```

At @COLDSPEED suggestion, you could group all these arguments and call `join` on them:

```
arguments =  [serverId, 
              name,
              host,
              str(port),
              proto,
              user,
              password,
              key,
              company,
              officeAddr,
              state,
              country,
              ladmin,
              phone,
              mobile,
              email,
              designation,
              reportingMgr]

print(';'.join(arguments))
```

Comment: While you're at it, I'd recommend a way to extract all these arguments neatly (as a list, say) and call `';'.join` on them ;-)

Comment: Hey, beats typing everything out manually. Lazy people make good programmers. :-)

Comment: But, i did convert it to str above when i write `port = str(args.port)` . Does it not get converted then? And thanks, since it did work. :)

Comment: Yes, you do, however, you are assigning port again in the function scope: `    port = 8888  # socket server port number`... Maybe a remnant of some debugging code?

Comment: Answer accepted as you did point me to the problem that I had and provided me with a better approach for the same as well. I will use the `';'.join` as well, but wanted to ask whether it is faster than concatenating the string? Faster in compilation, to be specific..!

Comment: The easy answer is that `join` is faster than string concatenation. This is due to the fact that strings are immutable, and a new string has to be created to append concatenate. However, in this case, it probably doesn't matter. Further, I noticed that on later versions of python, string concatenation (using `+`) was sometimes faster than `join`... It may be the result of some implementations, and this result is not guaranteed in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Replace following line

```
port = 8888  # socket server port number
```

with

```
port = '8888'  # socket server port number
```

Or you can type cast before forming connection string as string concat operations should be done only with another string i.e. replace

```
sum = serverId+";"+name+";"+host+";"+port+";"+proto+";"+user+";"+password+";"+key+";"+company+";"+officeAddr+";"+state+";"+country+";"+ladmin+";"+phone+";"+mobile+";"+email+";"+designation+";"+reportingMgr
```

with

```
sum = serverId+";"+name+";"+host+";"+str(port)+";"+proto+";"+user+";"+password+";"+key+";"+company+";"+officeAddr+";"+state+";"+country+";"+ladmin+";"+phone+";"+mobile+";"+email+";"+designation+";"+reportingMgr
```